# DevExpress Gridview - format rows in C# based on certain condition

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am using DevExpress GridView and binding data via C# code.

My requirement is to change the row color based on the calculation I perform in my code logic.

I want to traverse through all the rows available and if the row cell value matches the condition's result I need to change the color.

I have seen examples and sample source on the web but nothing seems to point me to resolve the issue. Most of them are using XAML code or using DataBinding or during DataBound etc. I am not so comfortable using inotifyvaluechange.

Look forward to your support and suggestions.

Comment: Can you not use GridView's Format rules (via Designer)?

Answer (score 2):

Try this for DevExpress Gridview

```c#
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid;

private void gridView1_RowStyle(object sender, 
DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowStyleEventArgs e) {
   GridView View = sender as GridView;
   if(e.RowHandle >= 0) {
      string category = View.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle, View.Columns["Category"]);
      if(category == "Beverages") {
         e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Salmon;
         e.Appearance.BackColor2 = Color.SeaShell;
      }            
   }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
private void grvAssesse_RowCellStyle(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowCellStyleEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.RowHandle >= 0)
  {
    GridView View = sender as GridView;        
    if (Condition)
    {
      e.Appearance.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
  }
}
```

You need to set condition globally, on the basis of that condition grid will execute this event for each row loading.

**For More details refer:** [GridView](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument758)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the HtmlRowPrepared event for changing the color of the row.

below is the example which could help you :

```
   protected void ASPxGridView1_HtmlRowPrepared(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewTableRowEventArgs e) {
        if (e.RowType != GridViewRowType.Data) return;                    
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan; // Changes The BackColor of ENTIRE ROW
            e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed; // Change the Font Color of ENTIRE ROW
    }
```

You can also set some condition so that only few rows would be coloured for example :

```
 protected void ASPxGridView1_HtmlRowPrepared(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewTableRowEventArgs e) {

    if (e.RowType != GridViewRowType.Data) return;       
     int VALUE = Convert.ToInt32(e.GetValue("COLUMNNAME"));
          if (VALUE < 20)          
       {
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan; // Changes The BackColor of ENTIRE ROW
                e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed; // Change the Font Color of ENTIRE ROW
        }
}
```

Comment: Ruchi, I think i forgot to mention. Sorry! I am using the WPF control not the ASPX.

Comment: I think this article might help you :

Comment: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowCellStyletopic